# How to convert a time series data into a live streaming video

Tags: graph, video-streaming

There is a event going on..it goes for 2 hours and at each second it creates new series data. How can I take this data(x=[],y=[]),convert into a graph and then convert it into a video live stream and then see it? 
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this but it seems possible.

First, you create a PNG with the graph using http://www.gnuplot.info.

> Gnuplot is a portable command-line driven graphing utility for Linux, OS/2, MS Windows, OSX, VMS, and many other platforms. [...] It was originally created to allow scientists and students to visualize mathematical functions and data interactively, but has grown to support many non-interactive uses such as web scripting.

You can create a script that routinely updates the PNG with new data.

There is also a node.js module to interface with gnuplot.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotframes

Then, you could use FFmpeg to create an HLS stream looping an image over and over again.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 30000/1001 -i graph_960x540.png -an -s 960x540 -r 30000/1001 -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -maxrate 900k -b:v 900k -profile:v baseline -bufsize 1800k -pix_fmt yuv420p -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename 'png2hls/file%03d.ts' png2hls/index.m3u8
```

However, is a video stream required to display a graph? Why not display the image and use JavaScript to update the image as new graphs are produced?

Cheers.